# How to fit Poission distribution with large mean?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, data-analysis

I have one set of discrete data plotted below. I suspect the data follows Poisson distribution with mean $\mu \simeq 400$ and standard deviation $\sigma \simeq \sqrt{400} = 20$.

$$ n(k) = \frac{\mu ^k}{k!} \exp (- \mu)\ \ \ (\mathrm{eq}.1)$$

But how can I confirm this? I tried numerically to calculate (eq.1) but, as you expect, it overflowed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Central Limit theorem - a Poisson distribution with a large mean is extremely similar to a discretized normal. With standard deviation $20$, each of those integer points will represent a $z$-score range of $.05$ - from $-0.025$ to $0.025$ at $400$, from $0.025$ to $0.075$ at $401$, and so on. The peak at $400$ should be a probability of about $\frac1{20\sqrt{2\pi}}\approx 0.02$.

You're getting numbers that are nearly twice that. Empirically, it looks like your hypothesized model is wrong, and the data is clustered tighter than a Poisson distribution would be.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me a lot. I have to reconstruct the model though.

Comment: On that, there's a quantitative way to check - you should have enough data there to estimate the variance.

Comment: I repeated the calculation 500 times but the result didn't change. After some research, it turned out that the model (actually this is Erdos-Renyi random graph model) was not wrong but my estimation "it should always follow Poisson distribution" were incorrect. Now I have what I wanted. Thank you again.